# adding colors using operator overloading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is a sample of input and output

```
Sample Input:
First Color: red
Second Color: yellow
Sample Output:
Color formed: Orange
```

this is my code.

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, clr):
        self.clr = clr
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Color(self.clr + other.clr)


C1 = Color(input("First Color: ").lower())
C2 = Color(input("Second Color: ").lower())
C3 = C1 + C2
print("Color formed:", C3.clr)
```

and when I run it, I get 'redyellow' as my output. But I need to get 'orange'. What should I do to get 'orange'? (I have to use only one constructor and one method tacking the addition operation of the colors. In the problem, it said no other methods are required to solve this)

P.S. This is a smaple question for practice. Not a homework question.

Comment: Storing colors using their names can take up a lot of effort and time, so using their RGB values and calculating using those would probably be easier to use.

Comment: you will get `redyellow` because you are overloading `+` operator

Comment: You defined your addition operation to return the color initialized by concatenating the names of the two input colors. Why are you surprised that red + yellow == redyellow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it returns "redyellow" is because this is how strings are added to each other in python. In order to get the result you want you will need to add if statements to your `__add__`.

For example,

```py
class Color:
    def __init__(self, clr):
        self.clr = clr
    def __add__(self, other):
        if (self.clr == "red" and other.clr == "yellow") or (self.clr == "yellow" and other.clr == "red"):
            return Color("orange")
```